# What is the quickest way to level up skills required to upgrade the Hideout?

Tags: escape-from-tarkov

In Patch 12.2, with the recent change to skills leveling, it's been challenging trying to meet the requirements to upgrade the Hideout.

What would be some of the quickest ways to do so?

**Skills in Question:**

- Strength (Level 3) for Vents (Level 3)
- Metabolism (Level 3) for Nutrition Unit (Level 3)
- Vitality (Level 3) for Medstation (Level 3)
- Health (Level 2) for Medstation (Level 2)
- Memory (Level 8) for Library
- Attention (Level 3) for Intelligence Center (Level 2)

Comment: I've had the game since 2017 and played on and off but they didn't change how you level skills but merely rate limited it didn't they?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot They added "exhaustion" to skills, which makes it a bit harder to level up, but I am also wondering how to actually level them up as well.

Comment: The [wiki](https://escapefromtarkov.gamepedia.com/Character_skills#) is probably your best bet. Each skill has a page with a “How to raise” section. They want skills to take ages to level though so I wouldn’t be surprised if even more changes in the future.

Comment: Whether you update this or not is whatever, but these requirements have changed in recent patches. And skill leveling is a little easier in some cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to make short summary without needs to visit wiki:

1. Strength was hardest for non-abusing play style and is a serious
   showstopper. You have to grab AND throw as many grenades you can buy
   or find in raid. Also, already standing on the exit area hit your
   teammates with melee weapon in legs and arms to not kill, but just
   deal some damage. Use RDG (smoke) and Zarya (flash) each raid as they are cheapest.
2. Metabolism and Nutrition - eat all you find in raid and cannot put in your safe pouch, except most expensive food items. Not a
   problem.
3. Vitality and Health will be of necessary level if you play game and not spend all time on Flea market.
4. Memory and Attention - not a problem, will be much higher if you play game and not buying your way through.

**Strength + Vitality Levelling Combo**

This was my method I (Camouflaged Cow) used to help level up both Strength and Vitality.

1. Bring a lot of grenades into the raid (to level strength). Make sure to bring one fragmentation grenade.
2. Save one fragmentation grenade to commit suicide with.
3. Throw all of your grenades except one at a safe distance.
4. Throw a grenade at your feet and suicide. Each death by grenade helps level Vitality by 1-1.5 points.
5. Rinse and repeat.

**Metabolism Levelling**

This was my method I (Camouflaged Cow) used to help level up my Metabolism.

1. Get several jars of DevilDog Mayo and a couple of Aquamari bottles.
2. Get into a raid and eat the DevilDog Mayo to bring your hydration all the way down.
3. Drink about 50 of the Aquamari for each jar of DevilDog Mayo.
4. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: I heard that walking (not sprinting) around over-encumbered also levels your strength.

Comment: @JAD, According to wiki yes, but it would be much harder (and expensive) to intentionally level-up Strength that way in comparison to knifing your mates and/or grenade-jumping.

Comment: @JAD It does, overweight walking levels strength. People take tank batteries in their container to do it I think.